# ANKI CSS/HTML: How to make Tags in browser "Position: fixed" in the bottom right corner, without the tags overlapping?

Tags: html, css, anki

See video for more detail on question:
https://streamable.com/td4k8j

I have all my tags visible on review, but I want them in the fixed position (i.e. doesn't move with scroll) in the bottom right. When I try this, they all overlap in the bottom right, how can I separate them?

I don't know a lot about HTML/CSS, and this is as far as I could get with common sense, please could answers be as specific as possible including the code? It's fine if not, thank you for your time.

**Front Code (HTML):**

```
<b id="tags-container">{{Tags}}</b>
<script>
var tagContainer = document.getElementById("tags-container")
if (tagContainer.childElementCount == 0) {
 var tagList= tagContainer.innerHTML.split(" ");
 var kbdList = [];
 var newTagContent = document.createElement("div");


 for (var i = 0; i < tagList.length;  i++) {
  var newTag = document.createElement("kbd");
  newTag.innerHTML = tagList[i];
  newTagContent.append(newTag)
 }
 tagContainer.innerHTML = newTagContent.innerHTML;
 tagContainer.style.cursor = "default";
}
</script>
{{/Tags}}
```

**Styling Code (CSS):**

```
/* TAGS */
/* Clickable Tags (need to download the add-on) */
kbd {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 0.05rem 0.1rem !important;
  margin: 1px !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1.5px !important;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  opacity: 0.5;
  vertical-align: right;
   word-break: break-all;
}


/* Tag Becomes More Visible On Hover */
kbd:hover { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.2s ease; }


/* Tag Colors */
kbd:nth-of-type(1n+0) { border-color: #fc00ff; color: #fc00ff; }
kbd:nth-of-type(2n+0) { border-color: #03A9F4; color: #03A9F4; }
kbd:nth-of-type(3n+0) { border-color: #FF0000; color: #FF0000; }
kbd:nth-of-type(4n+0) { border-color: #faed27; color: #faed27; }
kbd:nth-of-type(5n+0) { border-color: #FF9933; color: #FF9933}
kbd:nth-of-type(6n+0) { border-color: #ff6ec7; color: #ff6ec7; }
kbd:nth-of-type(7n+0) { border-color: #8ffcff; color: #8ffcff; }
kbd:nth-of-type(8n+0) { border-color: #ff009a; color: #ff009a; }
kbd:nth-of-type(9n+0)  { border-color: #39ff14; color: #39ff14; }
kbd:nth-of-type(10n+0) { border-color: #1b03a3; color: #1b03a3; }


/* Tag Mobile Adjustments */
.mobile kbd { opacity: .9; margin: 1px !important; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px !important; }
.mobile #tags-container {line-height:0.6rem; margin-left: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

apply the `position: fixed` to their container, not to the elements themselves. If there is no dedicated container for them, create one...